# How to get unicode name from a string character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

Basically wondering how to implement this function:

```
var char = 'a'
char.charCodeAt(0) // 97
getUnicodeNumber(char) // 0066 <- don't know how to find
```

Wondering if there's a library that has all of this data built into it somewhere open sourced, or if it's built into JavaScript, or how to do it generally.

Found that unicode number by looking on Wikipedia, but I'm wondering how to do it dynamically.

Comment: this will do trick https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js

Comment: Are you sure that 0066 is correct? 97 in decimal is 61 in hexadecimal. Otherwise, could you link to that page in Wikipedia, please?

Comment: I got that from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin), oh you're right it is 0061 :p